# for what values of $x$ is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n(1 + (x ^2) n) }$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{\ln(n+1)}$ converging

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

These are two separate questions. For the second series, it can possibly be an alternating series since $\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$. Other than that I am not sure how to find the x values to make them converge? thanks a lot

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Oh okay thanks, sorry I'm new to this @Shaun

Comment: your first sum converges for $$|x|\le 1$$ and $$x\ne 1$$

Comment: I doubt you mean $1+(x^2)n$. Maybe $(1+x^2)^n$? Or $1+x^{2n}$?

Comment: for your second sum must be also $$|x|<1$$

Comment: sorry i meant n(1+(x^2)n) @thomas Andrews

Comment: @Dr. Sonhard Graubner how would you prove that and how did you come up with those numbers?

Comment: use the Ration test

Comment: @Dr. Sonhard Grauber could you at least show me how you did the first series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $$a_n=\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$$ then we have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2\left(\frac{(\frac{1}{n}+x^2)}{\frac{1}{n+1}+x^2}\right)$$
and for the second series we get
let $$a_n=\frac{x^n}{\ln(n+1)}$$ and $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{x\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}\right)}{1+\frac{\ln(1+\frac{2}{n})}{\ln(n)}}$$

Comment: sorry but the question was (x^n)/n(1+n(x^2))

Comment: i will add this also for the second series

Comment: What did you mean by |x|≤1 and x≠1? Shouldn't it just be |x|<1?

Comment: Sorry again but the question x/n(1+n(x^2)). There was no x^n

Comment: no then must be also $$x\ne -1$$

Comment: the first question was just x/n(1+n(x^2)) there was no x^n in the numerator

Comment: yes it is corrected right now

Comment: Wouldnt the answer change now since the x^2 cancel each other out

Comment: in the second sum?

Comment: in the first series second sum because both 1/n and 1/n+1 go to 0 as n goes to infinity

Comment: yes in the first sum you will Need $x\ne 0$ only

Comment: that means x can be any number except for 0?

Comment: yes i think so and also WA

Comment: sorry what do you mean by WA?

Comment: it is Wolfram Alpha

Comment: Oh okay so for the first series it should be x can be any real number except for 0 and for the second series it should |x|≤1 and x≠1?

Comment: it must be only $|x|<1$